# TypeORM save nested objects

Tags: json, one-to-many, typeorm, many-to-one, nested-object

I'm working on a express (with TypeORM) + ReactJS app.

The problem is that I have 3 entities linked by OneToMany relationship like this:

1. customer
2. product(linked to customer)
3. model(linked to product)

```
import { Product } from './product.entity'

@Entity('customer')
export class Customer extends BaseEntity{
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    readonly id: number;
   
    @Column ({name: 'name'})
    name : string;

    @Column ({name: 'test', nullable: true})
    test : string;

    @OneToMany(() => Product, product => product.customer)
    // @JoinColumn({ name: 'product_id' })
    products: Product[]
}
```

```
import {Customer} from './customer.entity'
import {Model} from './model.entity'

@Entity('product')
export class Product extends BaseEntity{
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    readonly id: number;
   
    @Column ({name: 'name'})
    name : string;

    @Column ({name: 'test', nullable: true})
    test : string;

    @Column ({name: 'deleted', nullable: true})
    deleted : string;
    
    @ManyToOne(() => Customer, customer => customer.products)
    @JoinColumn({ name: 'customer_id' })
    customer: Customer;

    @OneToMany(() => Model, model => model.product)
    @JoinColumn({ name: 'customer_id' })
    models: Model[]
}
```

```
import { Product } from "./product.entity";

@Entity('model')
export class Model extends BaseEntity{
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    readonly id: number;
   
    @Column ({name: 'name'})
    name : string;

    @Column ({name: 'size', nullable: true})
    size : string;

    @Column ({name: 'deleted', nullable: true})
    deleted : string;
    
    @ManyToOne(() => Product, product => product.models)
    @JoinColumn({ name: 'product_id' })
    product: Product;
}
```

The save method from Express is:

```
  static add = async(req: Request, res)=> {
    const connection = getConnection();
    const queryRunner = connection.createQueryRunner();
    await queryRunner.connect();
    await queryRunner.startTransaction();
    try {
      let customer: Customer
      customer = await queryRunner.manager.getRepository(Customer).findOneOrFail(req.body.id)

      const productsReq: Array<Product> = req.body.products
      productsReq.forEach(async (product: any) => {
        let updatedProd =  {...product, customer: customer}
        const savedProd = await queryRunner.manager.getRepository(Product).save({...updatedProd})
        product.models.forEach(async (model: any) => {
          let updatedModel = {...model, product: savedProd}
          await queryRunner.manager.getRepository(Model).save(updatedModel)
        });
      });

      await queryRunner.commitTransaction();
      return res.send('Saving done')

    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
      await queryRunner.rollbackTransaction();
      res.status(500).send('Some error occurs');
    } finally {
    }
  }
```

Currently, in the DB, I have the following data:

1 customer with id 30

| name | id | test |
| --- | --- | --- |
| first customer | 30 | test column |

1 product with id 119 linked to customer 30

| id | name | test | customer_id | deleted |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 119 | first product | test column | 30 |  |

2 models with ids: 90 and 91 linked to product 119

| id | name | size | deleted | product_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 91 | second model witout id | 2000 |  | 119 |
| 90 | first model with id | 1000 |  | 119 |

Next, from React i'm trying to update only the model with id 90 and add a new model.
(So i'm not sending to backend all the models, model with id 91 is not sent).

The JSON object sent from frontend to backend looks like this:

```
{
    "id": 30,
    "name": "first customer",
    "test": "test column",
    "products": [
        {
            "id" : 119,   
            "name": "first product",
            "test": "test column",
            "models": [
                {
                    "id": 90,
                    "name": "first model with id",
                    "size": 1000
                },
                {
                    "name": "second model witout id",
                    "size": 2000
                }
            ]
        }

    ]
}
```

But the problem is in DB the foreing key "product_id" on table "model" is set to null for model with id 91 and a new row(92) is inserted.

The result is:

```
|id|name|size|deleted|product_id|
|--|----|----|-------|----------|
|91|second model witout id|2000|||
|90|first model with id|1000||119|
|92|second model witout id|2000||119|
```

How can I add a new model and update an existing one without sending all the existing models in DB ?

Answer (score 0):

I think i found a solutions.

I changed the save method from Express like this:

```
  static add = async(req: Request, res)=> {
    const connection = getConnection();
    const queryRunner = connection.createQueryRunner();
    await queryRunner.connect();
    await queryRunner.startTransaction();
    try {
      let customer: Customer
      let customerReq: any = req.body
      customer = await queryRunner.manager.getRepository(Customer).findOneOrFail(req.body.id)
      const productsReq: Array<Product> = req.body.products
      
      productsReq.forEach(async (product: any) => {
        let updatedProd =  {...product, customer: customer}
        let addedModels: Model[] = []
        product.models.forEach(async (model: any) => {
          const updatedModel = await queryRunner.manager.getRepository(Model).save({...model, product: product})
          addedModels.push(updatedModel)
        });
        const existingProd = await queryRunner.manager.getRepository(Product).save({...updatedProd})
        await (await existingProd.models).push(...addedModels)
        const savedProd = await queryRunner.manager.getRepository(Product).save({...updatedProd})
      });

      await queryRunner.commitTransaction();
      return res.send('Adding ok')

    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
      await queryRunner.rollbackTransaction();
      res.status(500).send('Something went terribly wrong');
    } finally {
      console.log('release')
      // await queryRunner.release();
    }
  }
```

It's strange becouse 2 transaction are started:

```
query: START TRANSACTION
query: SELECT "Customer"."id" AS "Customer_id", "Customer"."name" AS "Customer_name", "Customer"."test" AS "Customer_test" FROM "customer" "Customer" WHERE "Customer"."id" IN ($1) -- PARAMETERS: [30]
query: SELECT "Customer"."id" AS "Customer_id", "Customer"."name" AS "Customer_name", "Customer"."test" AS "Customer_test" FROM "customer" "Customer" WHERE "Customer"."id" IN ($1) -- PARAMETERS: [30]
query: COMMIT
query: SELECT "Model"."id" AS "Model_id", "Model"."name" AS "Model_name", "Model"."size" AS "Model_size", "Model"."deleted" AS "Model_deleted", "Model"."product_id" AS "Model_product_id" FROM "model" "Model" WHERE "Model"."id" IN ($1) -- PARAMETERS: [132]
query: SELECT "Product"."id" AS "Product_id", "Product"."name" AS "Product_name", "Product"."test" AS "Product_test", "Product"."deleted" AS "Product_deleted", "Product"."customer_id" AS "Product_customer_id" FROM "product" "Product" WHERE "Product"."id" IN ($1) -- PARAMETERS: [119]
query: INSERT INTO "model"("name", "size", "deleted", "product_id") VALUES ($1, $2, DEFAULT, $3) RETURNING "id" -- PARAMETERS: ["second model witout id",2000,119]
release

 Morgan -->  POST 200 /test @ Tue, 04 May 2021 14:28:08 GMT ::ffff:127.0.0.1 from undefined PostmanRuntime/7.28.0

query: START TRANSACTION
query: SELECT "Product"."id" AS "Product_id", "Product"."name" AS "Product_name", "Product"."test" AS "Product_test", "Product"."deleted" AS "Product_deleted", "Product"."customer_id" AS "Product_customer_id" FROM "product" "Product" WHERE "Product"."id" IN ($1) -- PARAMETERS: [119]
query: UPDATE "model" SET "size" = $2 WHERE "id" IN ($1) -- PARAMETERS: [132,8000]
query: COMMIT
```